# Adding to $PYTHONPATH with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I wrote a bash script to add to my `$PYTHONPATH`. My `.sh` file has the following:

```
sudo echo export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/new/python/module >> ~/.bashrc
```

What I want to be added to my `.bashrc` is:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/new/python/module
```

However I can only get it to add:

```
PYTHONPATH=/all/other/python/modules/already/on/path:/path/to/new/python/module
```

I don't want the actual `$PYTHONPATH` value to be added to my `.bashrc`, just the variable name. Please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use single-quotes:

```
$ echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/new/python/module' >> .bashrc
$ cat .bashrc 
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/new/python/module
```

The shell does not perform variable expansion on single-quoted strings.

Note also that, if you are writing to `~/.bashrc`, you should not need `sudo`.  A user should own his own `~/.bashrc`.  Further, as written, the `sudo` command only operated on `echo`.  The redirection `>~/.bashrc` is done with the user's level of permission.  Since `echo` has no need of and gets no benefit from `sudo`, `sudo` is a practically a no-op. [Hat tip: tripleee]

Comment: Maybe emphasize that it's lucky that the `sudo` doesn't do anything here; if it did, you could create a file which the user cannot later modify.  Luckily, here, the `sudo` is a complete no-op, because the redirection causes the user's shell to create the file before `sudo echo` starts executing.

Comment: @tripleee Very good point.  Answer updated with sudo-echo discussion.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/caff-dir/python'
```

Also, you may need to run following:

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```